# XML prefix doesn't show up when no defined URI in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net

Basically I was trying to generate an XML with the following format:

```
<m:MessageHeader>
  <m:Date>2017-09-14></m:Date>
  <m:Source>Web</m:Source>
</m:MessageHeader>
```

Below is my code:

```
Dim msgheader As XmlNode

msgheader = xml.CreateElement("m", "MessageHeader", "")
```

However, the prefix 'm' doesn't appear in the MesssageHeader. Below is the output of the above code:

```
<MessageHeader />
```

What should I do to get my expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you must specify the NamespaceUri.

If you leave the NamespaceUri parameter empty or null, the prefix is omitted.

try:

```
msgheader = xml.CreateElement("m", "MessageHeader", "https://stackoverflow.com/")
```